# Add Google Analytics Library to a Maven Project

Tags: android, maven, google-analytics

Where I can find the Google Analytics Android lib `groupId` and `archetype` for my projects pom?

I've been searching for it for a couple of hours, and I can't find any clue...(

P.S. I found something on GitHub, but it seam like it uses an third-party repository (when I try to run `mnv install` or `compile` it gives me an error):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.android.analytics</groupId>
  <artifactId>analytics</artifactId>
  <version>2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Maps, analytics and other Android jars are not fully maintained in any online Maven repository AFAIK, Just download them via Android SDK manager and install to local repository yourself, more in [this similar discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385664/cant-find-maven-dependency-for-google-apis-to-use-maps/10392014#10392014).

Comment: thenks... but it realy becomes an issue, when you work in a team... I hope that some day google will fix that...

Comment: You can always create your own maven repos and host them on GitHub or something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install all missing android libs using [maven-android-sdk-deployer](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer). 
It installs all extras in **local** maven repository from android sdk folder. Usage is quite simply: download and run `mvn install`. Deployer itself doesn't support optional dependencies other than sdk version. You **must** install all jars via SDK Manager at first.

*Update:* Upon writing this answer Google has landed updates to SDK Manager and included 2 maven repositories in it: `Google Repository` and `Android Support Repository`. All you have to do is add them to repositories list in `pom.xml`. It provides following artifacts:

- support library (v4, v13)
- gridlayout (v7)
- google play services (3.1.36)

As you can see it doesn't have analytics artifacts, so you still need `maven-android-sdk-deployer`

Comment: Thx, may be for some one it will come in handy. 
In our company we decided to use a local maven repository, and keep all unsupported libs there.

Comment: what should I write in build.gradle instead of: compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar') ? Something like: compile 'com.google.analytics:Analytics:3.+' ?

Comment: Analytics wasn't added to maven repo. So you still have to use `compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')`

Comment: @mente What URLs should be used for "Google Repository" and "Android Support Repository" ?

Comment: @DavidAndreoletti these repositories are installed locally with Android SDK. If you're using Gradle build system it's already included and you don't need to do anything

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Google Analytics SDK v4, Google Analytics is part of Google Play Services.
There's no need for a separate dependency anymore.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/changelog