# Maven dependency for libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar in Android

Tags: android, maven, google-analytics

The dependency configuration in mavens pom.xml for the Google Analytics lib 1.3 looked like this:

```
  <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.android.analytics</groupId>
          <artifactId>analytics-v2</artifactId>
          <version>r2</version>
  </dependency>
```

Now I have upgraded to Google Analytics lib V2 (libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar) but I can't find any dependency configuration examples...

I don't think that I am the only one who tried to use the new analytics library in android... so, is there anybody out there who knows a solution?

Comment: At present, most of Google APIs add-ons are not well-maintained in any online Maven repository, there is no standard name convention out there. When install the jars locally (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385664/cant-find-maven-dependency-for-google-apis-to-use-maps/10392014#10392014)), you are free to use any groupId and artifactId and version to install the jar and reference them correspondingly in your project.

Comment: i have tried this method before... but as maven is running on a ci-server, it doesn't work =(

Answer (score 1):

Use https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer to create local artifacts based on the SDK. This should also create the appropriate dependency POMs for you.